# IIS url rewrite to /applicationname/url

Tags: asp.net, api, iis, url-rewriting

When I browse to my web API from IIS:

The URL is: http://localhost:8099/applicationname

I need this to be http://localhost:8099/applicationname/someurl

Answer (score 0):

You can use rule in IIS.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule1">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:0}/someurl" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="applicationname" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

It can work well.
[image]